# cannot type inside webview in android4.0

Tags: android, webview

i want to type something in the edittext boxes dispalyed in the webview.When i am loading the webview in android2.2 device it is working fine. But unfortunately it is not working in android4.0. I did not get any hint from any other posts.given below is my code.

```
        mWebView.clearSslPreferences();
        mWebView.setInitialScale(0);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        mWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN); //to show the keyboard
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(webClient);

        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();
            if(hr!=null){
            if(hr.getType()==HitTestResult.EDIT_TEXT_TYPE )
                ((Activity) context).setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);

            else
                ((Activity) context).setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
            return false;  
            }     
        }); 

    return v;
```

please tell me why this is happening?any solution for this?

Comment: Do you have an edittext (other than the webview) ?